# How to learn and use SharePoint Server 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

My boss wants to implement SharePoint Server 2013 in our company which is a small government firm of around 30-40 employees (and will expand later). He wants me to do certifications for it. I have a background of some programming in Visual Studio in C# but not that good (as I am a copy & paste coder). He wants me to Install, Implement and later develop apps in SharePoint Server 2013. I haven't used SharePoint Server before. Could anyone guide me the right path to take in order to start using SharePoint Server 2013 and also could you let me know which learning materials and certifications do I need to take for it?

Comment: I may be pessimist, but I don't believe a single average developer, with no SharePoint experience can maintain both the infrastructure and the applications. Maybe you can try SharePoint Online (Office 365), to at least having the platform maintained by someone else. SharePoint has a very hard learning curve. You should also be helped by some experimented team to start, to avoid common mistakes, and to learn how to attack the monster.

Comment: Can't we just get started at least with the learning path? Having something is better than having nothing.

Comment: My bast advise, is to start to use SharePoint before trying to develop. Try to modelize some small applications with no code at all. Try to explore the many features available OOB. Only open Visual Studio when you are comfortable with the usage of SharePoint. If not, you will risk to try to reinvent the wheel, or to apply some patterns you may know where it's not a good idea. Good luck still

Comment: @SteveB! Thanks for your comment. Which certifications do I need to take first?